# Number of Paths to get from One point to Another

Tags: combinatorics, permutations, combinations

[image: grid]
What are the total number of paths that can be taken to get from point A to point B ?
Rules :-
1)You can move up ,down ,left , right
2)You CANNOT return to a point that you have been to before ie no crossing your own path
3)You CANNOT move diagonally

(I have tried a similar problem ,wherein you could move only up or to the right , which was pretty easy)
(Also if a general formula can be given for l*b grid , it will be appreciated)

Comment: self-avoiding paths of indeterminate length are rather harder to count than shortest paths

Comment: Yess thats the entire problem

Comment: See [here](https://oeis.org/search?q=self+avoiding+path+&language=english&go=Search).

Comment: Not bad , however thats using bruteforce on a computer . Isnt there a mathematical way to solve this problem ?

Comment: Again empirically: you could find that out by brute force, using grids of size 2x2 and 3x3 etc and establish a series, which has already been given to you.

Comment: Thats one way , but I'm looking for a more mathematically rigorous method to solve this rather than using the help of machines

Comment: So that's pencil and paper ;)

Comment: Hahaha yes , that would take up lots of paper .

Comment: Is there anyway to arrive at an answer without using brute force or empirical evidence.

Comment: Counting the number of self-avoiding walks is a notoriously difficult problem.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is a self avoiding walk problem. There is no known formula for a generic $m \times n$ grid. In fact it is rumored that this is a computationally hard (NP hard problem).

The particular grid of $4\times 4$ is doable. It comes out to be $184$. If it helps, I can upload a small python/matlab script.

NJA Sloane's IS has it listed for a set of grid size $n \times n$, unto $n=10$: http://oeis.org/A007764

There is a nice article on self avoiding walk (aptly titled 'How to avoid yourself') by Brian Hayes in American Scientist (I couldn't find the exact link, but here is a copy sourced in the internet. http://www.peterbeerli.com/classes/images/f/fa/AmSci1998Hayes.pdf)

Comment: To compute the number of paths, one needs to find the longest path. The longest path problem(https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Longest_path_problem) itself is NP complete. Hence, for arbitrary $n$, this indeed is a hard problem.